# yandex Structured data validator API

Tags: ajax, cross-domain, microdata, yandex

I try to create corrected self-exercise on microdata with Structured data validator API of Yandex. I need to send yandex api the content of textarea to know if it contain the good microdata.
I read developer's guide and i decided to use validation for html with ajax request.
https://tech.yandex.com/validator/doc/dg/concepts/html-validation-docpage/

My code :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#valid').click(function(){
        $data=$('#data').val();
        $apikey="myapikey";
        $lang="en";
        $pretty="true";
        $id="1";
        $only_errors="false";

        $url="https://validator-api.semweb.yandex.ru/v1.1/document_parser?apikey="+$apikey+"&lang="+$lang+"&pretty="+$pretty+"&id="+$id+"&only_errors="+$only_errors;
        
        $.ajax({
            url: $url,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $data,
            success: function (data) {
                //

            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);

            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<textarea id="data" name="textarea"
          rows="10" cols="50">
text with microdata
</textarea>
<button id="valid">Envoyer</button>
<textarea id="reponse">

</textarea>
```

I have a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource".

I don't understand how i can do an ajax request with this api because

- I need use POST so i can't use jsonp
- I can't work server side so i can't modify header

Can you help me ?

Comment: Your api key works are you sure??

Comment: Try $only_errors="true"; to see what hapent

Comment: @george : api key works because i see good response in network developer tools and change only_error have no effect

Comment: The No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin gives you Yandex or your server. if this gives you the Yandex you cannot do anything .if this is from your server just allow the Access-Control-Allow-Origin.